# Category based search

Tags: magento-1.7

I am using the mini search in my sites header and it only works partially.. Here\’s the problem:

When I search a product name, it will only find the product when i supply the corresponding category id.

This does NOT work: 
/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?q=searchterm

This DOES 
/index.php/catalogsearch/result/?cat=123&q;=searchterm

This is what I am trying to achieve: 
I want the searchform to always search within every category, without using the $_GET[\’cat\’] variable.

Would really appreciate some help here, because it\’s practically driving me crazy..

Answer (score 1):

I got solution I had combine quick search and advance search by using if else condition if text box is clicked search will be redirect to quick search action if category dropdown is select search will be redirect to advance search

Answer (score 0):

Please check on there are some extension or some  code is modify.Else root category is not working